# Using library with Google play service vision

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to add a library that uses google play service vision. My library works well on a native android project as long as I add the play service vision lib to the app. I have added the following build hints in a Codename One project:

[image]
With that build hint i have the following build error:

```
/tmp/build731648870085799025xxx/MyApplication/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml:64: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar'.

    /tmp/build731648870085799025xxx/MyApplication/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/materialbarcodescanner-release/res/values/values.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowActionBar'.

    /tmp/build731648870085799025xxx/MyApplication/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/materialbarcodescanner-release/res/values/values.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowNoTitle'.

    /tmp/build731648870085799025xxx/MyApplication/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/values/values.xml:69: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light'.
```

That issue is not related to the google play service lib: I have the same issue when I try to use a simple library that just uses a toastbar. Perhaps android studio generated some resources that can not be used in codename one ?

When I try to change the google play service version with the following build hint:[image]

The google play service lib is not found anymore:

```
 Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-vision/10.0/play-services-vision-10.0.pom
     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-vision/10.0/play-services-vision-10.0.jar
     file:/tmp/build3506878302752944909xxx/MyApplication/libs/play-services-vision-10.0.jar
     file:/tmp/build3506878302752944909xxx/MyApplication/libs/play-services-vision.jar
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-vision/10.0/play-services-vision-10.0.pom
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-vision/10.0/play-services-vision-10.0.jar
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-vision/10.0/play-services-vision-10.0.pom
     file:/home/ec2-user/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-vision/10.0/play-services-vision-10.0.jar
 Required by:
     :MyApplication:unspecified
```

How can I change the google play service version and how can I add my libraries properly ?

Comment: I'm looking into this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `android.playServicesVersion` to `10.0.0` or `10.0.1`.  Either of those should work.

Comment: This resolves my issue with the play service thank you. Do you have any clue how I can solve the second issue that occurs when I try to add an aar android native library in Codename one ?

Comment: It's unclear what the second issue is from the question?

Comment: Sorry I think I shoud have written two questions. I am trying to use an external aar android library. This library works on a native android app but i have a build error with Codename One. See the first block of code in my post: some resources are missing. This is happening with a library I have created with android Studio. I have this issue even if I only put one class with a toast method. If that' is unclear I will ask a new question. Thank you for your concern @ShaiAlmog

Comment: That's too partial. I think I'll need the full log. It's easier to just submit multiple questions rather than multipart questions as far as I'm concerned. From what I can gleam it seems the AAR has some dependencies on theme elements that are now missing

Comment: I will submit a new question as soon as possible.